# Count data from multiple csv files

Tags: vba, excel

I've got hundreds of folders in links to them in a shared folder
Eg:

```
a:\Images\abc\year\month\date\names1
a:\Images\abc\year\month\date\names2
a:\Images\abc\year\month\date\names3 etc,.
```

Each folder has a csv in it (*`abc.csv`* constant name in each folders) containing few info.

Eg:

```
1 Orange USA
2 Apple England
3 Orange Australia
4 Orange Austria
5 Apple India
```

Here I would like to count the number of Oranges, Apples, Grapes and Melons in CSV of 
Different Folders.

I'm expecting output like:

```
Link    Oranges Apples  Grapes  Melon

\names1 5846    2000    85215   586

\Names2 4521    1542    45852   125

\Names3 365     4856    25415   548
```

Kindly Help...

Comment: where do the numbers come from? count of occurences in the csv file or sum of row numbers? No commas in your csv? Always one space before and after the data you want to count on?

Comment: Is the range of items (Oranges Apples  Grapes  Melon) defined or can a csv file have new items that would cause the creation of a new column?

Comment: and when you say "I've got hundreads of folders in links to them in a shared folder". Do you have links in an excel file already, or is it just subfolders of a specific constant folder?

Comment: what is your solution so far? if you would like a `VBA` solution then what `VBA` have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It will open the file abc.csv contained in each folder listed in columns(1), count the items, then close the file and move on.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountApples()
Dim wbk As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, wbkTemp As Workbook, lLoop As Long, lLastRow As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Set sht = ActiveSheet

lLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For lLoop = 2 To lLastRow
    Set wbkTemp = Workbooks.Open(sht.Cells(lLoop, 1) & "\abc.csv")

    sht.Cells(lLoop, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Columns(1), "Oranges")
    sht.Cells(lLoop, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Columns(1), "Apples")
    sht.Cells(lLoop, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Columns(1), "Grapes")
    sht.Cells(lLoop, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wbkTemp.Sheets(1).Columns(1), "Melon")

    wbkTemp.Close (False)
Next lLoop

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Nutsch you are really a genious but for few security reasons I'm taking out some info.... I apologise and Thanks a ton you are a true genious in VBA